# Convert lambda expression to expression tree

Tags: c#, linq

i do a linq query:

```
        var parcels = (from parcel in Db.Parcels
                                where
                                    (parcel.Neighbors.Count(neig =>
                                        {
                                            var neigType1 = neig.Neighbors as NeigType1;
                                            var neigType2 = neig.Neighbors as NeigType2;
                                            var result = false;
                                            if (neigType1 != null)
                                            {
                                                 result = neigType1.Name.Contains(NeigTextBox.Text);
                                            }

                                            if (neigType2 != null)
                                            {
                                               result = кадастроваяОрганизация.Name.Contains(NeigTextBox.Text);
                                            }
                                            return result;
                                        }) > 0)
                                select parcel).ToList();
```

But in line `(parcel.Neighbors.Count(neig =>` i get an error:

> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an
>   expression tree

Google says that it because i don't using `=>` operator. But where i gonne put it?

Comment: Most interesting part, I think, happens where `.....`

Comment: is result return bool type?

Comment: a little or on what you can do with Linq to Entities http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: it's just a select type of Neighbor. But i can edit code in question if it needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
var parcels = Db.Parcels
    .Where(p => p.Neighbors.Count(neig =>
        {
            .....
            return result;
        }) > 0)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Will this not throw the same error? You still have a lambda expression with a statement body...